# ipython up and down arrow strange behaviour

Tags: python, macos, ipython

In my installation of ipython I have this strange problem where I cannot reliably move through command history with up and down arrows... a lot of the time it just doesn't work (nothing happens on the key press). Also sometimes writing normal characters at the end of the command just doesn't work.

My system: Mac OSX Lion

I have readline installed...

thank you for the help!
david

Comment: Which frontend ? Classical ipython or qtconsole ? Which version ? 0.13.1 has been released a few hours ago. You can try to open a issue on github.

Comment: Matt, thank you for writing... To answer your question: classical ipython... I tried 0.13.1 and it's the same. Yes, maybe I'll open the issue - thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you installed readline **before** ipython.

`sudo pip uninstall ipython`

`sudo pip install readline ipython`

(I know this question is a few months old, but for future reference)

Comment: I didn't have to uninstall ipython. Just "easy_install readline" did the trick.

Comment: you need to install ncurses-devel (for redhat) or libncurses5-dev for debian/ubuntu if you get "-lncurses" not found error when running pip

Answer (score 5):

I had to install readline with `easy_install readline` and that fixed it.
Using `pip install readline` did not work for me, and ipython gave a warning:

```
******************************************************************************
libedit detected - readline will not be well behaved, including but not limited to:
   * crashes on tab completion
   * incorrect history navigation
   * corrupting long-lines
   * failure to wrap or indent lines properly
It is highly recommended that you install readline, which is easy_installable:
     easy_install readline
Note that `pip install readline` generally DOES NOT WORK, because
it installs to site-packages, which come *after* lib-dynload in sys.path,
where readline is located.  It must be `easy_install readline`, or to a custom
location on your PYTHONPATH (even --user comes after lib-dyload).
******************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Following trouble in iPython and up-&-down arrows to access history, and browsing  this post, a simple solution (turn off "Scroll lock") turned out to work for me.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: As @abarisone said, kindly elaborate on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an intentional feature of IPython. If you type "abc" and then hit the up arrow, it's going to scroll only through lines that start with "abc". If you hit lift/right while you're scrolling, it triggers the same behavior. The entire contents of the current line are interpreted as your search prefix, any only lines starting with all that will show up on further up/down keypresses.

You can change this behavior in your `PYTHONSTARTUP` file. I have the following lines:

```
import readline
# Prevent ctrl-p/ctrl-n/Up/Down from doing prefix searching 
readline.parse_and_bind('"\\C-p": previous-history')
readline.parse_and_bind('"\\C-n": next-history')
readline.parse_and_bind('"\\e[A": previous-history')
readline.parse_and_bind('"\\e[B": next-history')
```

If you're curious, [here are the bindings in IPython's source code](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/058dda2a8cfc39eaa2541300f577af95f2f407e5/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L418-L431) that we're overriding.

Unrelated, but I also like to to override readline's default ctrl-w:

```
# Ctrl-W behavior more like Vim
readline.parse_and_bind('"\\C-w": backward-kill-word')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by generalizing this functionality, so I wrote a function that can accept a list of indexes - some of them nested, some of them simple - and returns a sequence of items obtained by traversing the nested structure for each of the indices in turn. Because many structures can be simple keys of containers, I made a custom type to indicate that a given key should traverse the nested structure.

N.B. This is not thoroughly tested or production ready, and can probably be made more efficient and simpler with a bit more thought.

```py
>>> def nested_itemgetter(*args):
...     def _itemgetter(subscriptable):
...         rv = []
...         for a in args:
...             if isinstance(a, NestedIndex):
...                 temp_item = subscriptable
...                 for k in a:
...                     temp_item = temp_item[k]
...                 rv.append(temp_item)
...             else:
...                 rv.append(subscriptable[a])
...         if len(rv) == 1:
...             return rv[0]
...         return tuple(rv)
...     return _itemgetter

>>> class NestedIndex(tuple):
...     ...

>>> nested = [
...    [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'AA', 'Special number': 0.1}],
...    [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'BB', 'Special number': 0.15}],
...    [{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'CC', 'Special number': 0.05}]
... ]

>>> nested_itemgetter(0, NestedIndex((1, 1, "Special number")), NestedIndex((2, 0, "time")))(nested)
([{'time': 5, 'ask price': 8}, {'ID': 'AA', 'Special number': 0.1}], 0.15, 5)
```