# "Down arrow" moves cursor to end of line - how to turn it off

Tags: jupyter-notebook, codemirror, jupyter

In IPython Notebook / Jupyter, arrow up/down keystrokes within a cell are handled by CodeMirror (as far as I can tell). I use these actions a lot (re-bound to control-p / control-n) to move between cells; but at the end of every cell, the cursor **moves to end of line first** before jumping to the next cell. This is counter-intuitive and, to me, rather distracting.

Is there any way to configure CodeMirror to make this move down to be just that - a move down?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014946/ipython-up-and-down-arrow-strange-behaviour Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot - No; #13014946 refers to console ipython. My issue is with the notebook. Also, the behavior I am describing is that intended by the developers, so it's not a bug; I just don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that I wasn't alone in wanting to skip the "going to end of line" behavior when going down from the last line of a code cell, I investigated that behavior and found out that:

- it's *CodeMirror* that goes to the end of line when you type down in the last line of a code cell (file: `codemirror.js` ; "methods": `findPosV` and `moveV`)
- and it's *IPython* that decides what to do with the "down" event after it has been handled by CodeMirror (file: `cell.js` ; class: `Cell` ; method: `handle_codemirror_keyevent`) ; looking at the code, I saw that IPython ignores the event when not at the last character of the last line.

This essentially confirms Marijin's answer.

The primary goal being to jump to the next cell, I think there's no need to prevent CodeMirror from going to the end of that line. The point is to *force IPython* to handle the event anyway.

My solution was to change the code from `Cell.prototype.handle_codemirror_keyevent` to this:

```
Cell.prototype.handle_codemirror_keyevent = function (editor, event) {
    var shortcuts = this.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts;

    var cur = editor.getCursor();
    if((cur.line !== 0) && event.keyCode === 38){
        // going up, but not from the first line
        // don't do anything more with the event
        event._ipkmIgnore = true;
    }
    var nLastLine = editor.lastLine();
    if ((event.keyCode === 40) &&
         ((cur.line !== nLastLine))
       ) {
        // going down, but not from the last line
        // don't do anything more with the event
        event._ipkmIgnore = true;
    }
    // if this is an edit_shortcuts shortcut, the global keyboard/shortcut
    // manager will handle it
    if (shortcuts.handles(event)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

This code provides the desired behavior for the "down-arrow" key (almost: the cursor still goes to the end of the line, except that we don't see it, as we're already in another cell at that point), and also handles the "up-arrow" key similarly.

To modify the `handle_codemirror_keyevent` prototype, you have two possibilities:

1. You edit the `cell.js` file and change the code of the prototype to the code I gave above. The file is in `<python>/Lib/site-packages/IPython/html/static/notebook/js` or something similar depending on you distro
2. **Much better**, after the page is loaded, you change that prototype dynamically by doing this:

   ```
   IPython.Cell.prototype.handle_codemirror_keyevent = function (editor, event) {
       <same code as above>
   };
   ```

   You can do that in your `custom.js` for example, or [create an extension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions/wiki) to do it (that's what I did).

Comment: Nice. Works if the code per #2 is put inside `$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () { ...     return true; }); ` in `custom.js`

Answer (score 2):

The moving-to-next-cell behavior is defined by IPython wrapper code, which probably checks whether the cursor is at the end of the current cell, and overrides the default CodeMirror behavior in that case. You'll have to find that handler and somehow replace it with one that checks whether the cursor is on the last line. (I don't know much about IPython, only about CodeMirror, so I can't point you at the proper way to find and override the relevant code. They might have bound the `Down` key, or they might have overridden the `goLineDown` [command](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#commands).)